# why mysql data has a single quote when displayed in PHP?

Tags: php

Im new to php and i have this code tested with XAMPP at backend

```
$name = addslashes ($_POST['name']);
$email = addslashes ($_POST['email']);
$paswd = addslashes ($_POST['paswd']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO webusers (username,email,paswd)VALUES('$name','$email','$paswd')";
```

and here's my code for displaying data
    include_once('dbcon.php');

```
$db = mysql_select_db('test');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM webusers";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$urow = mysql_num_rows($result);

    echo"
        <table border='1'>

        <th>ID</th>
        <th>USERNAME</th>
        <th>EMAIL</th>
        <th>PASSWORD</th>
 ";

 if($result > 0){
 while($urow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){



    echo "<tr>";
    echo"   <td class='myinput'>'" .$urow['id']. "'</td>";
    echo"   <td class='myinput'>'" .$urow['username']. "'</td>";
    echo"   <td class='myinput'>'" .$urow['email']. "'</td>";
    echo"   <td class='myinput'>'" .$urow['paswd']. "'</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   

    echo"</table>";
    }
    }else{

echo"No record";

    }
  ?>
```

Those code works, except for the data which surprise me why it has a single quote when i show/display it on a table. though i input the data in html . and my magic_quote_gpc was off. is there something i missed or anything wrong with my code? or there is something with my database collation?

i also tried mysql_real_escape_string and mysql_escape_string, nothings change.

thanks for the help.

Otep

Comment: `echo"   <td class='myinput'>'" .$urow['id']. "'</td>";` you had used a single quote here for display..

Comment: You are adding the quotes echoing data in the table.

Comment: Don't use MySQL_* functions This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you put Single Quotes in the HTML ?

```
echo"
        <table border='1'>
       <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>USERNAME</th>
        <th>EMAIL</th>
        <th>PASSWORD</th>
       </tr>
 ";

 if($result > 0){
 while($urow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){



    echo "<tr>";
    echo"   <td class=\"myinput\">" .$urow['id']. "</td>";
    echo"   <td class=\"myinput\">" .$urow['username']. "</td>";
    echo"   <td class=\"myinput\">" .$urow['email']. "</td>";
    echo"   <td class=\"myinput\">" .$urow['paswd']. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   

    echo"</table>";
    }
    }else{

echo"No record";

    }
```

Try that, your code without Single quotes

Comment: This one works like a charm. thanks @Alexis Peters. what really  happen with my code? is my query literally read those single quote?

Answer (score 0):

You are printing a `'` around your values in your HTML Markup

```
echo "<tr>";
echo"   <td class='myinput'>" .$urow['id']. "</td>";
echo"   <td class='myinput'>" .$urow['username']. "</td>";
echo"   <td class='myinput'>" .$urow['email']. "</td>";
echo"   <td class='myinput'>" .$urow['paswd']. "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

is what you really want to echo

Comment: When i display the data in html table it appears like this 'data' which is not my intention.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if($result > 0){
 while($urow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){



    echo "<tr>";
    echo"   <td class='myinput'>" .stripslashes($urow['id']). "</td>";
    echo"   <td class='myinput'>" .stripslashes($urow['username']). "</td>";
    echo"   <td class='myinput'>" .stripslashes($urow['email']). "</td>";
    echo"   <td class='myinput'>" .stripslashes($urow['paswd']). "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   

    echo"</table>";
  }
}else{

echo"No record";

}
```

Comment: This one also work. those stripslashes, i just tried it earlier but in a wrong format thanks Sir.